# Javascript, CSS: относительные координаты DOM элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, позиционирование

Пишу небольшое веб-приложение, в котором один пользователь может перемещать объект по экрану, а другой наблюдать за перемещением этого объекта (передаются координаты). Но проблема в том, что у пользователей могут быть разные размеры окна. Чтобы это исправить я хочу использовать координаты не в пикселях а в процентах. То есть я делю число сто на ширину окна и получаю коэффициент, на который буду умножать координату по горизонтали. Также и по вертикали. Но проблема в том, что из-за размера элемента при разном размере окна элемент будет находится в разных местах. Как сделать, чтобы все работало как я хочу?

Вот как это выглядит:

```js
function fullscreen() {
  if (screenfull.enabled) {
    screenfull.toggle();
  }
}

function pos(elem) {
  var offset = elem.offset(),
    eh = elem.height(),
    ew = elem.width(),
    wh = $(window).height(),
    ww = $(window).width(),
    ol = offset.left,
    ot = offset.top;
  //wh=720,ww=1280;
  $('#x').text(ol.toFixed(0));
  $('#y').text(ot.toFixed(0));
  //$('#ew').text(ew.toFixed(0));
  //$('#eh').text(eh.toFixed(0));
  $('#winY').text(wh);
  $('#winX').text(ww);
  $('#xp').text((ol / ww * 100).toFixed(4));
  $('#yp').text((ot / wh * 100).toFixed(4));
}

$(".elem").draggable({
  drag: function() {
    pos($(this));
  },
  containment: "document"
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  pos($('.elem'));
});

$("#move").on('click', function() {
  move(50, 50);
});

function move(x, y) {
  var elem = $('.elem'),
    offset = elem.offset(),
    eh = elem.height(),
    ew = elem.width(),
    wh = $(window).height(),
    ww = $(window).width(),
    ol = offset.left,
    ot = offset.top;
  elem.offset({
    left: x / 100 * ww,
    top: y / 100 * wh
  });
  pos($('.elem'));
}

pos($('.elem'));
//console.log($(window).height());
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/3.0.2/screenfull.min.js"></script>
<div><i>Координаты x в процентах: </i>  <span id="xp"></span>
</div>
<div><i>Координаты y в процентах: </i>  <span id="yp"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="move">(50;50)</button>
</div>
<button onclick="fullscreen()">Fullscreen toggle</button>
<div class="elem">
  <div>x: <span id="x"></span>/<span id="winX"></span>
  </div>
  <div>y: <span id="y"></span>/<span id="winY"></span>
  </div>
  <!--  <div>width: <span id="ew"></span></div>
 <div>height: <span id="eh"></span></div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Задайте размер элемента в процентах

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал, но не хотелось бы, чтобы размер элемента изменялся

Comment: А как вы хотите-то тогда? Хотя бы нарисуйте несколько вариантов, что ли

Comment: Было бы неплохо, чтобы координаты считались не от угла элемента, а от центра

Comment: код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: исправил, только здесь он не работает почему-то

Comment: потому что не добавлена ссылка на jquery-ui. Поправил ссылки на библиотеки

Comment: Странно, я, вроде, добавлял. Спасибо